# Java WindowBuilder is not working, showing blank design page

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

I'm having problems wih WindowBuilder (latest version (4.4)) and Eclipse (Latest version (Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a))), WindowBuilder is showing a blank design page for no reason.

[image]

I got this error from Eclipse : https://dev.eclipse.org/recommenders/community/aeri/v2/#!/submissions/8uX9PiWcEwLe9ksMKQChiO5ImxRyccrp3cUIB5QWgOwe118MCarSb9knmVAzFLX5

Comment: If it was working before, then you could try deleting the .metadata of WindowBuilder. Your unique settings will be lost but your editor might work again.

Comment: "this error" is a dead link now...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was due to an error with 'Tabbed panes'. I had to change them for a JMenu instead.

Comment: Can you show where to change from 'Tabbed panes' to 'JMenu'?

Comment: I completely removed the TabbedPanes and changed them for JMenu. So instead of new TabbedPane() I used new JMenu()